# How do I turn off the productionTip warning in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 2 one could use

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

to turn off the `productionTip` warning on development builds. However it doesn't work with Vue 3:

```js
Vue.config && (Vue.config.productionTip = false);

const App = {
  data: () => ({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
};
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">{{ foo }}</div>
```

Comment: There are a couple of additional stack snippet-specific tips in the meta thread [How do I create a Vue.js Stack Snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417263/how-do-i-create-a-vue-js-stack-snippet/419282#419282)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#config-productiontip-removed) it was **removed**.

So, if you want to get rid of the warning in your Vue 3 Stack Overflow answers (without disabling the console in the snippet), you have to replace `src="https://unpkg.com/vue"` with a `global.prod` CDN build: (i.e: `src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.global.prod.js"`):

```js
const App = {
  data: () => ({
    foo: 'bar'
  })
};
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{ foo }}</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

productionTip has been defaulted to false for production in Vue 3.x. It's now only for dev. Check [Vuejs official documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#config-productiontip-removed).

Comment: The fact `productionTip` defaults to `false` in Vue 3 is no change from Vue 2. It has always been *"only for dev"*. What changed in Vue 3 is that you can no longer turn it off in development builds. So one is now forced to use a prod build if they don't want the warning. In 2.x you could just turn it off, as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

write this

```
const app = createApp(App)

app.config.warnHandler = function (msg, vm, trace) {
  return null
}
```

Done!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.